# System.IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to copy data from list to 2d array

Tags: c#, list, excel-interop

I am getting an exception:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

on col ++ when it is in the second loop. I am trying to put the vales from list> to excel columns and rows. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
object[,] cellValuesToWrite = new string[excelRange.Rows.Count, excelRange.Columns.Count];                
foreach (List<string> errorRecord in section.ErrorRecords)
{
    int rows = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int length = errorRecord.Count;
    foreach (var elem in errorRecord)
    {
        if (col < length)
        {
            cellValuesToWrite[rows, col] = elem;
            col++;
        }
    }
    rows++;
}
```

Comment: You're setting rows to 0 on the start of each loop.  Little point in incrementing it.

Comment: I want to add one errorRecord in single row and so on so forth.

Comment: I really don't get the point of filling each cell with the same element. However, probably `excelRange.Columns.Count` is 1 if you start from single selected cell. Can't you just debug it?

Comment: Not sure, if `excelRange.Columns.Count` and `errorRecord.Count` represent same number of columns ?

Comment: You should be able to get some insight from the debugger.  When it throws the exception, you should be able to see the values of `rows`, `col`, and the size of `cellsToWrite` and `errorRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you create the array with `excelRange.Rows.Count` and `excelRange.Rows.Count` is 5 you cannot access `cellValuesToWrite[5, col]` because indexing starts at 0 and you try to access the 6-th element this way.

Why not using a good old for loop (especially if you need indexing):

```
for (int row = 0; row < cellValuesToWrite.GetLength(0); row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < cellValuesToWrite.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        cellValuesToWrite[row, col] = section.ErrorRecords[row][col];
    }   
}
```

Comment: @SKh you are welcome. Try using more the debugger and stepping through the code line by line. You could have found the mistake on your own :)